# Updating SQL column type without losing relations

Tags: sql, prisma

I have the following model in my Prisma databse:

```
model Asset {
  id              Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  name            String?
  shapefile       Shapefile?
}
```

Where a `shapefile` belongs to an `asset`. I want to change the `id` type from `Int` to `String`. However, It's my understanding that when I make a migration, I will have to drop the current `id` column, and the corresponding `assetId` column in the `shapefile` table. If I then try to make a data migration afterwards, creating new `String`s for my `asset`s, I'm assuming that I will have no way to know which `shapefile`s belonged to which `asset`s. I think I can probably create a new column `newId` in `Asset` and `newAssetId` in `shapefile`, then make a data migration that creates those things relationally, then make another migration that renames `newId` to `id` and deletes the old `id`. However, it feels like there must be a better way to do this. Is there a good way to do this in one migration?

Comment: Are you saving the file contents in each cell? For spatial data you can use PostGIS to save spatial data and can then even be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty migration file and alter the contents to something like.

```sql
alter table asset alter column id type text using id::text;
```

You will however need to manage your default value since its a text it will no longer self increment. You could use `generate` to manually increment and cast to text every time. The current default will no longer work so you will have to remove the default

```sql
alter table asset alter column id drop default
```

Answer (score 0):

Migrating to string , you will losse your auto increment fetaure . If you need to convert int to string then some timestamp with milliseconds .
Then you use alter table asset alter <column_id>